# Namenode format does not free up datanode disk space

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

After shutting down the cluster `./stop-all.sh`, and then invoking a `hadoop namenode -format`, I see that the datanodes have the same disk space i.e. the space has not been freed up.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete manually data on DataNode before formatting NameNode

**rmr**

```
Usage: hadoop fs -rmr URI [URI …]
```

Recursive version of delete.
Example:

```
hadoop fs -rmr /user/hadoop/dir
hadoop fs -rmr hdfs://nn.example.com/user/hadoop/dir
```

Exit Code:

Returns 0 on success and -1 on error.

---

**Alternatively**

Data-nodes should be reformatted whenever the name-node is. I see 2 approaches here:

1. In order to reformat the cluster we call "start-dfs -format" or make a special script "format-dfs". This would format the cluster components all together. The question is whether it should start the cluster after formatting?
2. Format the name-node only. When data-nodes connect to the name-node it will tell them to
   format their storage directories if it sees that the namespace is empty and its cTime=0.
   The drawback of this approach is that we can loose blocks of a data-node from another cluster if it connects by mistake to the empty name-node.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-107

Answer (score 3):

On formatting the namenode, the space does not get cleaned up. One will have to do so manually.

To do that,

First stop the cluster by invoking `./stop-all.sh` or `./stop-mapred.sh` and `./stop-dfs.sh` in the correct order.

Then delete the data directory of the datanode, i.e either the directory specified by `dfs.data.dir` in `hdfs-site.xml` or by `hadoop.tmp.dir`/dfs/data

The option to do a `-rmr` (specified in one of the other answers to this question) before doing a format is actually the best way, unless you're like me who unknowingly formatted the namenode and THEN realized that the datanode space doesn't get cleaned up ;)

Answer (score 2):

Formatting a Namenode won't format the Datanode.

It will just format the contents of your namenode. i.e., Your namenode will no longer know
where your data is. Also namenode -format will assign a new namespace ID to the namenode

You will have to change your namespaceID in your datanode to make your datanode work.
This will be at dfs/data/current/VERSION

There is a JIRA open now for the same suggesting to format Datanode aswell when you format Namenode. [HDFS-107](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-107)